# What does '+i' mean in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

I ran across this while reviewing a colleague's code. She'd left it in by accident (it used to be a String concatenation), and I assumed that it wouldn't compile. Turns out I was wrong, so I tried seeing what that operator did:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = -1;
    System.out.println(String.format("%s", +i));
    System.out.println(String.format("%s", +i));
}
```

As far as I can tell, it does nothing, but I'm curious if there is a reason it's allowed to compile. Is there some hidden functionality to this operator? It's similar to `++i`, but you'd think the compiler would barf on `+i`.

Comment: That looks like a typo of `++i`

Comment: It was actually a String concatenation originally, but that was my thought too. `+i` and `++i` both compile, which is totally weird to me.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html, see *Unary plus operator*.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3

Comment: It's the counterpart to the unary negation operator `-`

Comment: Ah, so it doesn't do anything for negative numbers? It's just to be more explicit when defining a positive number?

Comment: Indeed, negative numbers won't be converted to positive, as in maths: `+(-x)` equals `-x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the [plus unary operator `+`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3). It basicaly it does [numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1), so "if the operand is of compile-time type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, it is promoted to a value of type `int`".

Another unary operator is the increment operator `++`, which increments a value by 1. The increment operator can be applied before ([prefix operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1)) or after ([postfix operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2)) the operand. The difference is that the prefix operator (`++i`) evaluates to the incremented value, whereas the postfix operator (`i++`) evaluates to the original value.

```
int i = -1;
System.out.println(+i);         // prints -1

System.out.println(i++);        // prints -1, then i is incremented to 0

System.out.println(++i);        // i is incremented to 1, prints 1
```

Comment: Here is a (slightly) more detailed reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3